# Objects not coming through for Kendo MVC Autocomplete UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I had this working at one point but I'm not sure what is breaking it now. Objects and object properties are not populating the drop down. I can get object properties to show up if I pass just an array of strings of one of the properties in my autocomplete controller but I would like to pass the whole objects to the autocomplete dropdown and style a template from there. I have been changing DataTextField and Template to simplify for this example and testing purposes but hasn't granted any success yet. Also now I am returning an array of Objects from my Parts_Read method and made sure that AllowGet was enabled. Do you notice anything I am missing?

View

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("parts_results")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .Template("#= VendorPartCode # | #= Name # | #= UpcCode #")
    .HeaderTemplate("<div class=\"dropdown-header k-widget k-header\">" +
                    "<span>Matching Parts</span>" +
                    "</div>")
    .FooterTemplate("Total <strong>#: instance.dataSource.total() #</strong> items found")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", @class = "form-control"})
    .Height(520)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("Parts_Read", "AutoComplete")
                .Data("onAdditionalData");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

Script

```
function onAdditionalData() {
    return {
        text: $("#parts_results").val(),
        supplier: $("#part_supplier").val()
    };
}
```

Autocomplete controller

```
public JsonResult Parts_Read(string text)
{
    int supplier = int.Parse(Request.Params["supplier"]);
    var search = Request.Params["text"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && supplier >0)
    {
        dbContext db = new dbContext();

        var data = db.dbParts.Where(x => x.PartSupplierCompanyId == supplier && (x.PartName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || x.PartCode.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))).Select(p => new TimsPart(p,p.Company)).ToArray();
        return Json ( data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet ); 
    }
    else
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new List<TimsPart>(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks good.  Is `Parts_Read` actually returning data?  What is the control displaying if you enter the minimum 3 characters?  Any JS errors in the browser console?  Does it make a difference if you remove the `Template` line from the control?

Comment: Ohh yes there is a relevant JS error actually. Circular reference while serializing. Got hidden with image reference errors. Thanks for the heads up. Should be able to take it from here.